# Flask+ Flask_SocketIO connection problems

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

Right now, I'm working on a project that is calculating and sending requests to a plotly.js webserver to write graphs, but I'm failing to get sockets to work.

Basically, I'm running website inside new thread using `asyncio.run_in_executor` function like this:

```
if self.config["local-tracking"]["switch"]:
    shared.trackingWebsite = MainWebsite()
    self.loop.run_in_executor(None, shared.trackingWebsite.start)
    print(f"Local website link: {self.c.Magenta}http://localhost:{self.config["local-tracking"]["port"]}/ {self.c.R}")
else:
    print(f"{self.c.DBlue}INFO {self.c.R}>> Webserver (tracker) is disabled.")
```

In `MainWebsite` class, I have the following code:

```
import logging, sys, flask, flask_socketio, typing, datetime, time, typing
sys.dont_write_bytecode = True
import src.connector as con

if True:
    from src.system.colors import C, CNone

class MainWebsite:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.sandbox: bool = con.read_shared("sandbox")
        self.c: C | CNone = con.read_shared("colors")
        self.last_time: datetime.date = datetime.datetime.now()
    
        self.app = flask.Flask(__name__)
        self.socketio = flask_socketio.SocketIO(self.app, namespace="/")
    
    
    def _setup_routes(self, sandbox: bool) -> None:
        @self.app.route("/")
        def main_route() -> str:
            return flask.render_template("sandbox.html") if sandbox else flask.render_template("main.html")
            
        @self.socketio.on("connect")
        def connect() -> None:
            pass
            
        @self.socketio.on("disconnect")
        def disconnect() -> None:
            pass
    
        @self.socketio.on_error_default
        def default_error_handler(e) -> None:
            print(f"Socket.IO Error: {e}")
    
    
    def make_update(self, action: typing.Literal["main", "rise", "fall"], y: int | float, x: datetime.datetime) -> None:
        try:
            if not self.sandbox:
                self.socketio.emit(action, {"y": y, "x" : int(time.mktime(x.timetuple())) * 1000}, namespace='/')
            else:
                self.last_time = self.last_time + datetime.timedelta(seconds=self.config["general"]["sandbox"]["interval"])
                print(f"Sending event: {action}, Y: {y}, X: {int(time.mktime(self.last_time.timetuple())) * 1000}")
                try:
                    self.socketio.emit(action, {"y": y, "x" : int(time.mktime(self.last_time.timetuple())) * 1000}, namespace='/')
                except Exception as error:
                    print(error)
            
         except Exception as error:
             print(f"{self.c.Red}ERROR{self.c.R} @MainWebsite.make_update: {type(error).__name__}: {error}")
    
       
    def start(self) -> None:
        self.config: dict = con.read_shared("config")
        self._setup_routes(self.config["general"]["sandbox"]["status"])
    
        log: logging.Logger = logging.getLogger("werkzeug")
        log.setLevel(logging.FATAL)
    
        try:
            self.socketio.run(self.app, host=self.config["local-tracking"]["host"], port=self.config["local-tracking"]["port"], debug=False)
        except Exception as error:
            print(f"{self.c.Red}ERROR{self.c.R} @MainWebsite.start: {type(error).__name__}: {error}")
```

So far, website starts, without any errors. Connections are also successful. But once I try to send an event over `make_update` function, server sends it, but client never recieves it.

[image]

Here is a part of client (webpage) code:

```
socket.on('connect', function() {
    console.log('Socket.IO connected!');
});

socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    console.log('Socket.IO disconnected!');
});

socket.on('error', function(error) {
    console.error('Socket.IO error:', error);
});

socket.on('main', function(data) {
    console.log('Received main event:', data);
    try {
        Plotly.extendTraces('live-chart', {x: [[new Date(data.x)]], y: [[data.y]]}, [0]);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error processing main:', error);
    }
});

socket.on('rise', function(data) {
    console.log('Received rise event:', data);
    Plotly.extendTraces('live-chart', {x: [new Date(data.x)], y: [[data.y]]}, [1]);
});

socket.on('fall', function(data) {
    console.log('Received fall event:', data);
    Plotly.extendTraces('live-chart', {x: [new Date(data.x)], y: [[data.y]]}, [2]);
});

socket.onAny((event, ...args) => {
    console.log(`Received event: ${event}`, args);
});
```

I think (not 100% sure) I'm using `eventlet`. Monkey patching didn't work either.

Comment: The python-socketio package supports asyncio. If your main back end application is asynchronous I suggest you use an async Socket.IO server as well, to reduce the complexity of your solution. The fact that you are not sure if you are running eventlet or not is concerning. Eventlet is not going to be easy to host alongside an asynchronous application. It's not impossible to do, but you have to have a good understanding of it to pull it off.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Before 2 days ago, webserver ran successfully (without `eventlet`), but now it dies with error `ValueError: Invalid async_mode specified` (if I don't use `eventlet`, reason why I wasn't sure yesterday of what I'm using as none of the "fixes" from internet worked for me).  Error also says tha EngineIO fails to load `self.eio = self._engineio_server_class()(**engineio_options)` from file `.venv\Lib\site-packages\socketio\base_server.py`. I'm not entirely sure what's causing the failure. But for sure, `eventlet` doesn't handle socket events.

Comment: To me it does sound like you are not sure what configuration you are using, and you are not sure you want or need eventlet. So why are we even talking about eventlet if you don't care about it? Unfortunately without accurate details of the configuration it is impossible for me to help you. The hybrid implementation that you have is really a bad setup, and as I said it is unnecessary since Socket.IO can run under asyncio.

Comment: I am sure what configuration I'm using. Normal `async_mode="threading"`, which for some reason, doesn't run anymore. As I said in previous comment, `eventlet` ran the webserver, but broke SocketIO as it was a fix recommended from internet. If you checked my question, I'm not using `python-socketio`, but `flask_socketio`. My confusion only relates to the fact on why whole webserver broke without any backend and frontend change. May I ask what hybrid implementation and bad setup? There is nothing more than starting webpage with `flask` and connecting socket with `flask_socketio`.

Comment: As you said, I'll go ahead and try to implement `socketio.Server` logic under `asyncio` and hope it will run. Also going to update my question and try to make it more clear, with provided all error messages etc. Hopefully that will clear things out.

Comment: What I meant by hybrid implementation: You have an asynchronous application that is putting a synchronous web server inside a thread executor. The standard way would be to use an all-async or all-sync application.

Comment: I understand. Surprisingly, my code was fully correct and working. I guess I deleted `from engineio.async_drivers import threading` on accident and broke the `EngineIO` initialization. I've managed to get it to work now :)

Going to do a question update + answer sometime tomorrow, thank you for help.